# Linking Swing Components

Tags: java, swing

[My GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL01G.png)
I need some kind of foreach loop to go through all of the components in the content pane and add the values into a map.

```
HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The String from the Drop Down box will be the Key and the value will be the contents of the Day and Week `JTextField` components (maybe with a ';' so I can split later).

So far I can't figure out how to link the components together or if that is even possible (even if there is a hacky way around it).

Comment: Can you say `JTable`

Comment: *"Hopefully my question is clear."* Technical point. Those words contain no question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your components are inside JPanel you can try this:

```
for(Component comp : jPanel1.getComponents()){
                if(comp instanceof JComboBox){
                    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)comp;
                    System.out.println("cb.getName() = "+cb.getName());
                    System.out.println("cb.getSelectedItem() = "+cb.getSelectedItem());

           }
}
```

Comment: Okay, simpler idea, create a `JPanel` which contains a `JComboBox` and two `JTextField` with appropriate getters/setters, then you could just use a `LIst` or `Map` to manage them, better yet, use a `JTable`